# Display Message Box Before Deleting Sheet MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to prevent users from deleting a spreadsheet that is used as a template for a daily report. The users are supposed to change the name of the spreadsheet to today's date (i.e. 01-14) and then run a macro that creates a copy of today's sheet and renames it "New Day". I need to make sure the users cannot delete the "New Day" sheet as it contains formulas. I am suck working with MS Excel 2007.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: protect the Structure of the workbook [see this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Password-protect-worksheet-or-workbook-elements-dbf706e0-ba22-4a08-84d8-552db16eef11#bmprotectworkbookelements)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Protect Sheet` on the original sheet.

Go to `Review` to `Protect Sheet`. Make sure the "Protect worksheet and contents of locked cells" is selected, and if you don't type in a password, the sheet is protected, but someone COULD potentially un-protect with some effort. If you're only worried about them accidentally deleting the sheet though, this definitely could help.

Comment: [Protect Sheet] doesn't prevent the deletion of the worksheet. I can lock out the cells and prevent editing within the worksheet, but I can't prevent the loss of the worksheet itself. Do you know of any event driven approach to stop the process in the same way as the built in warning message.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me this morning on Excel 2010, Just test it on 2007 and let me know.

Paste the following into the specific sheet Module.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   ThisWorkbook.Protect "yourpassword"
 End Sub

 Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
   ThisWorkbook.Unprotect "yourpassword"
 End Sub
```

This works perfectly in Excel 2010 allowing me to edit and delete cells/rows/columns.

Then when you want to Copy it you will need to `Select` another sheet to view, because as soon as the specific sheet is selected it will apply the password which will remove the selection to Move/Copy/delete. This will apply to the Copied sheets as well.

```
Sub SomeSub()

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet

    Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Due to the the Protection of the Sheet while it is active
    'you then need to select another sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    'With the Sheet not being active you don't need to unprotect it
    'because the password is not applied.
    MySheet.Copy After:=Sheets(2)

    'Note that the Copied Sheets will be protected with the
    'same password used for the original sheet, and this Only applies with access through VBA.

End Sub
```

Let me know if there is anything more to explain or if it isn't working.

Comment: Protecting the sheet doesn't prevent deleting the sheet, which seems odd to me, but I've tested it a few different ways. Each time I can delete the worksheet even with all of the cells locked and in-selectable.

Comment: @Andrew have a look at the updated answer and give it a try. As soon as you active the sheet it protects it while allowing it to be edited. then you will just need to unprotect the Sheet when you want to copy it and then Protect it again when you finished copying it.